# C while loop until user enters "quit"

Tags: c, string, scanf

Here's my code:
1. User types in two names, with a space in between. This means that two strings need to be read. I.e. input: 
    John Doe.

1. The strings are then checked in a char-array. (works fine).
2. The while loop goes on until the user types "stop" - only "stop".
   How can I make it to stop directly if "stop" is entered - without the need to check the second string?

The code:

```
while(bool==false)
{
    scanf("%20s%20s", name1, name2);

    if(strcmp(name1, "stop")==0)
    {
        break;        
    }
    // but still the second name has to be entered

    rest of code...

}
```

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Please prefer `!bool` instead of `bool == false`.

Comment: Why not read the manual page for `scanf` and note the return value bit

Comment: @MarounMaroun Why? Isn't that just a matter of personal taste? I'm more worried about the use of `bool` as a variable, as it may be a preprocessor macro defined as `_Bool`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This may cause problems, imagine `bool = false` instead of `==` (people tend to do that).. Also I see it redundant because asking `bool == false` is like asking "if something is false, is true".

Comment: Is `bool` a reserved word? Anyway not very good name for a variable

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Yoda programming?

Comment: @EdHeal Can solve this.. but still.. why to ask "if equal false is true" :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I agree it is just like saying: `if ( bool == true ) return true; else return false`, just `return bool`

Comment: Always check return value of `scanf` functions. In paticular, if there is problem with code that uses `scanf`, double check you do this fo all return values, as first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to get the input, check for the `"stop"` string, and then use [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to parse the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can put to use the regular expression character class support provided by `scanf`.

You could do:

```
scanf("%s%[^\n]s", name, temp);
```

Here, your first word is mandatory while second is optional.

When you input 2 words, your `temp` would have a leading space.
If you want to directly avoid it, you can do so by:

```
char *p = temp;
scanf("%s%[^\n]s", name, p++);
```

Here, you can later access your 2 words using `name` and `p`